# Filling between boundaries

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to visualize what it graphically means to integrate between two boundary values. Therefore I'd like to make a `Filling` between these two values. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Something like this (source code is free there) ?http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntegrationIsASum/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An alternative is to use **`Piecewise`**  as follows

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Piecewise[{{Sin[x], -Pi <= x <= Pi}}, _]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, Yellow}}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Directive[Red, Thick]}]
```

which gives

[image]

Or

Use **`Show`** to superimpose two variants (the second one with your choice of the variable bounds -- `-Pi` and `2Pi` in the example below) of the plot:

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}], 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, - Pi, 2 Pi}, 
         Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Yellow]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Yet another method using **`ColorFunction`** with `ColorFunctionScaling->False`, `Mesh` and `MeshShading`,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 π}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Directive@{Thick, Blue}}, Filling -> Axis, 
   ColorFunction -> (If[-Pi <= #1 <= Pi/2, If[#2 > 0, Red, Yellow], White] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** All inside **`Manipulate`**:

First, a cool combo control from somewhere in the docs:

```
 popupField[Dynamic[var_], list_List] :=  
   Grid[{{PopupMenu[Dynamic[var], list, 0, 
          Opener[False, Appearance -> Medium]], 
          InputField[Dynamic[var], Appearance -> "Frameless"]}}, 
  Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Orange, 
  Background -> {{Orange, Orange}}]
```

and, then,

```
Manipulate[Column[{ Dynamic@Show[ Plot[func[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 π}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic},
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Directive@{Thick, color0}},
  Filling -> Axis,
  ColorFunction -> (If[lb <= #1 <= ub, If[#2 > 0, color1, color2], White] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> {600, 300}],
  Graphics[{Gray, Line[{{-2 Pi, 0}, {2 Pi, 0}}],
   Orange, PointSize[.02], Dynamic[(Point[{lb = Min[First[pt1], First[pt2]], 0}])],
   Brown, PointSize[.02],  Dynamic[(Point[{ub = Max[First[pt1], First[pt2]], 0}])]},
  PlotRange -> 1.], PlotLabel -> Style[ "\nArea = " <> 
    ToString[Quiet@NIntegrate[func[t], {t, lb, ub}]] <> "\n", 
   "Subsection", GrayLevel[.3]]]},  Center], 
 Row[{Spacer[30], Rotate[Style["functions", GrayLevel[.3], 12], 90 Degree],
  Spacer[5],Control@{{func, Sin, ""},  popupField[#, {Sin, Cos, Sec, Cosh, ArcSinh}] &}
  Spacer[15], Rotate[Style["colors", GrayLevel[.3], 12], 90 Degree],
  Spacer[5],  Rotate[Style["line", GrayLevel[.3], 10], 90 Degree],
  Control@{{color0, Blue, ""}, ColorSlider[#, AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum",
           ImageSize -> {40, 40}, AutoAction -> True] &},
 Spacer[5], Rotate[Style["above", GrayLevel[.3], 10], 90 Degree],
 Control@{{color1, Green, ""}, ColorSlider[#, AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum", 
          ImageSize -> {40, 40}, AutoAction -> True] &},
 Spacer[5], Rotate[Style["below", GrayLevel[.3], 10], 90 Degree],
 Control@{{color2, Green, ""}, ColorSlider[#, AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum", 
           ImageSize -> {40, 40}, AutoAction -> True] &}},Spacer[0]],
 {{lb, -Pi}, ControlType -> None},
 {{ub, 3 Pi/2}, ControlType -> None},
 {{pt1, {-Pi, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 {{pt2, {3 Pi/2, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 Alignment -> Center, ControlPlacement -> Top, AppearanceElements -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Enter your own pure function:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I liked the second code snippet of yours with the _Show_ command, the best. One thing though, the filling is better done with _Filling->0_ instead of _Filling->Axis_

Answer (score 13):

I made [an answer by J.M. and Murta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19202/21534) into a function:

```
IntegralPlot[f_, {x_, L_, U_}, {l_, u_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{col = ColorData[1, 1]},
  Plot[{ConditionalExpression[f, x > l && x < u], f},
   {x, L, U},
   Prolog -> {{col, Line[{{l, 0}, {l, f /. {x -> l}}}]}, {col, 
      Line[{{u, 0}, {u, f /. {x -> u}}}]}},
   Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
   PlotStyle -> col,
   opts]]

IntegralPlot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x], {x, -4, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

[image: IntegralPlot_PDF]

```
IntegralPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, {4, 6}, PlotLabel -> "x^2"]
```

[image: IntegraPlot_x2]

Comment: Nice idea to capture the functionality within a function.

Answer (score 10):

With axis-constrained locators:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {Pi, 0}}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts[[1]] = {#[[1, 1]], 0}; pts[[2]] = {#[[2, 1]], 0}) &],
 Dynamic[
   Framed@Show@
          {Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
           Plot[Sin@x, {x, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}, Filling -> Axis] 
          }
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

This is the full code, with the label:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {Pi, 0}}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts[[1]] = {#[[1, 1]], 0}; pts[[2]] = {#[[2, 1]], 0}) &],
 Dynamic[
   Framed@Show@
          {Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
            PlotLabel -> ToString@StandardForm[Integrate[sin[x], 
                         {x, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}]] <> " = " <> 
                         ToString[Integrate[Sin@x, {x, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}]]],

           Plot[Sin@x, {x, pts[[1, 1]], pts[[2, 1]]}, Filling -> Axis] 
          }
   ]]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Area will be red or blue depending whether $b > a$ or not.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[x], UnitStep[Sign[b - a] (x - a)] UnitStep[Sign[b - a] (b - x)] f[x]}, 
    {x, -7, 7}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thickness[0]}, Filling -> {2 -> 0}, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], If[b - a > 0, Red, Blue]], 
  PlotLabel -> "AREA = " <> ToString[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]]], {{b, 4}, -7, 7},   
   {{a, -1}, -7, 7}, {f, {Sin, Cos, Tanh, Sech}}]
```

[image]

[image]

Also take a look at source code at the [**Wolfram Demonstration Project**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=area%20integrate).

Answer (score 3):

Copying the second code snippet of user kglr's answer I changed the command `Filling->Axis` into `Filling->0`.

```
(*start*)
integrationLimit1 = 1;
integrationLimit2 = 8;
f[x_] = 100 - 8*x^2 + x^3;
g1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 10}];
g2 = Plot[f[x], {x, integrationLimit1, integrationLimit2}, 
   Filling -> 0];
Show[g1, g2]
(*end*)
```

Also, the order of the graphics `g1` and `g2` in the `Show` command are important.

[image: showing integration limits]

Answer (score 1):

Always search the doc when you don't know what to do. In most cases you'll not only find it possible, but find a thorough documentation along with examples. In this case you have [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html).

Here is an example:

```
Show[
 Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}],
 Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, π/4, 5/4 π}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, All} , Filling -> 1 -> {2}]
]
```

[image: output image showing filling between curves]

Comment: Thx for the answer, but what I would like to do is to shade just one of these function between two boundary values.

Comment: @rainer I simply supplied an example. If you want to fill it in alternatively look through the documentation for Filling.