# How to plot filling under a curve?

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to mark critical areas for statistical test on the plot. How can I do this? This:

```
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]
Show[Plot[pdf, {x, -5, 5}], 
 Plot[pdf, {x, -5, -2.001}, Filling -> Axis]]
```

gives:

[image]

I know that it is probably some super-duper Mathematica feature, but as far as I know this filling shouldn't be cut in such strange way, so I don't want to use this feature. How can I make the filling look right?

Comment: Look at your second plot separately and you'll see it is cut too. Why should it be drawn completely when you combine the two graphs? Try `PlotRange->All` in your second graph which ensures that the whole curve is plotted.

Comment: PlotRange->All does not work either. But it works very well for x in <-4,4>. Mathematica knows which numbers are inappropriate! And if it decided that {-5,5} is wrong, and should cut the plot, it is right :p

Comment: looking at @J.M.'s answer in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/how-can-i-fill-under-a-function-in-a-plot-just-to-right-of-a-specified-vertical you could also do (avoiding show): `With[{dist = PDF[NormalDistribution[], #] &}, 
 Plot[{ConditionalExpression[dist[x], x < -2], dist[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 1]]]`

Comment: You have to use `PlotRange->All` **inside** your second plot, not in the `Show`.

Comment: Thanks. But still Mathematica takes my breath away. It even knows that when I want to plot something, it inteligently assumes that i don't want to plot it in the whole. Wow! ;)

Comment: @Misery That's a convenience feature.  Compare `Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 2}]` with `Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]`.  If `PlotRange -> All` were the default people would surely complain about this example I gave. It is the default, so people complain about other examples. We can't eat the cake and have it too ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the `Plot` where you have the fill only plots up to a y-value of around 0.03 (try it on its own, without the second plot which shows the whole range) which means that you don't have a fill all the way to the top of where it appears in the graph. You can correct this by forcing it to plot to a higher value of `y` using the `PlotRange` option. You can either specify exactly the `PlotRange` you want, or simply give it the option `All`.

```
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]
Show[Plot[pdf, {x, -5, 5}],Plot[pdf, {x, -5, -2.001}, Filling -> Axis, 
PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Note that where you put the `PlotRange` option is important. If you don't include it in the filled graphic then that graphic will be evaluated in the standard way and thus won't include the information for the filling up to the point you want. If you include the `PlotRange` option as an option in `Show`, or as an option in the first plot then it will not effect the information coming from the filled plot.

In general the non-default options for Show are taken from the graphics elements from the first one on. If the first element has `PlotRange->{0,3}` and the second has `PlotRange->{0,4}`, then the option for the whole graphics object will be `PlotRange->{0,3}`. It is worth playing with the different values for the `PlotRanges` in the following to see what is happening:

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}],Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}], PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

This particular set of options will give you the following plot but if you alter the values in `PlotRange` above, you will see how Show is taking these options. Try also without the final `PlotRange` to see which option it takes and how the graph looks:

[image: examples of plotrange options]

Comment: Without explaining *why* it works now, the answer is useless for inexperienced users of *Mathematica*. If you don't know the reason for sure, only the fix, then give it a shot. You probably get corrected by the community, but you definitely learned something yourself.

Comment: No! It is very useful! Mathematica just has so many features, and is so inteligent... and so on. According to the saying: "It's not a bug! It's a feature". I learned its philosophy by heart and now I am happy that I spent so much money for this... ekhm miracle of software engineering!

Comment: using this approach, you better `Clear@x` before defining `pdf` (or use `pdf := PDF[NormalDistribution[], #] &` and then `pdf[x]` in the plots) (or is there an easier way?)

Comment: @Misery I was referring to other users finding this question and hoping for an explanation of the behavior. Assume a slightly more difficult problem and having a more complex solution without any explanation.

Comment: It was in new session of Mathematica so x didn't exist. But it is a vital suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan: I know. But I am soooo disappointed with Mathematica and it's philosophy "It's not a bug, it's a feature" that I don't expect any good explanation exists. But You're absolutely right. Hope I didn't upset you.

Comment: @halirutan, my apologies, you are right. This was not a very useful answer. I'll add some notes as to what's going on.

Comment: @halirutan There are many comments (useful or not),  explanations why each answer works. Also statement that separate second plot is cut, so it will be cut in `Show` is not very helpful for beginners because what is missing is Why the second plot is cut. That is strange for beginners. Well, I'd love to see good explanation.

Comment: @Kuba The simple explanation is that `Show` uses the options of the first argument, so sometimes the second one can get truncated if you don't pass the right options.

Comment: @rm-rf First plot contains area truncated in second at the end so I do not understand Your explanation. Moreover, separate second plot is truncated, that's my point, that's the "feature" which is strange for beginners. I still do not know why it is so.

Comment: @Kuba, this is because within the Show, the information from the filled plot simply isn't there if you don't have the `PlotRange` option in it. Compare: `Show[Plot[pdf, {x, -5, -2.001}, Filling -> Axis], PlotRange -> All]` with `Show[Plot[pdf, {x, -5, -2.001}, Filling -> Axis,PlotRange -> All]]`. The list of non-default options from the graphics elements are concatenated in the `Show` command but if there are multiple possibilities for the same option then it will use the first one that shows up in the elements being displayed.

Comment: @Kuba I'll admit it might be a bit strange for a beginner, but it's documented. The plotting functions try to show the region that is "most interesting" (or the range where most of the y values are). For example, try this: `Plot[Sinc[x] - Piecewise[{{Sin[x]/x, Abs[x] < 2}}, 1], {x, -2.01, 2}]` with and without `PlotRange -> All`. It is up to the user to verify and modify according to their needs. Since each person's definition of "interesting" varies, I think this compromise is reasonable. Of course, those advocating for explicit options have nothing to lose, since you can still be explicit.

Comment: @Kuba, I've added an explanation to the answer which shows a little more about how `PlotRange` can be used in `Show`.

Answer (score 7):

Putting [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk)'s comment into an answer:

```
With[{dist = PDF[NormalDistribution[]]}, 
 Plot[{If[x < -2, dist[x]], dist[x]}, {x, -5, 5},
  Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 1]
 ]
]
```

Observe that `ConditionalExpression` is not needed as a simple and concise `If` is sufficient, and `If` also works in version 7 which the former does not.

---

Regarding your sarcastic comment:

> But still Mathematica takes my breath away. It even knows that when I want to plot something, it inteligently(sic) assumes that i don't want to plot it in the whole. Wow! ;)

If you do not like the narrowed range you can use `PlotRange -> Full` to show the full plot range even if it is empty space.  You can also use `SetOptions` to make this setting the default for one or more functions.

Comment: I figured it was just copying J.M.'s answer, hence the comment. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution. The idea is constructing another function (`Piecewise[{{0, x <= -2}}, pdf]`) for `pdf` to fill, then you can fill the plot in a common style.

```
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[], x];
Plot[{pdf, Piecewise[{{0, x <= -2}}, pdf]}, {x, -5, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Comment: Simple and smart. Like it.

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

```
With[{pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[]], cv = -2.001},
 ParametricPlot[{x, t pdf[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{cv}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], ColorData[1][1]], None}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
 ]
```

[image: ParametricPlot output]

Two-tailed:

```
With[{pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[]], cv = 2.001},
 ParametricPlot[{x, t pdf[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{-cv, cv}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[0.2], ColorData[1][1]], None}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
 ]
```

Right-tailed (note the reversal of `MeshShading`):

```
With[{pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[]], cv = 2.001},
 ParametricPlot[{x, t pdf[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{cv}}, 
  MeshShading -> {None, Directive[Opacity[0.2], ColorData[1][1]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
 ]
```

Comment: @LCFactorization You'e welcome! and thank you very much, too.  I like it, too (of course, I guess). :)

Comment: Sophisticated and smart. Like it too !