# How do I fill the area from 0 to pi in my Sine wave and in the process get the area value?

Tags: plotting

I am new to Mathematica and I tried searching the docs but no specific examples there.

This is what I have achieved so far, returns an error, probably wrong syntax.

```
Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Range {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: Try `Plot[{If[0 < x < Pi, Sin[x]], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]` For area take a look at `Integrate`.

Comment: To get the area: `Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, and bills: I need a single value for the area. Anyway, can Mathematica could do this automatically, with a special function that allows me to integrate and in the process, it does the shade.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the process"? Do you want an animated graphics with shading increasing along time and some text indicating the area of current shaded region?

Comment: **To the close voters:** how is this *easily found in the documentation*? The OP did not merely ask how to compute the area under the curve, but how to do it "in the process" of plotting.  I believe my answer describes this, and I cannot recall seeing that in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no *"special function that allows me to integrate and in the process, it does the shade"*, but you can shade the area and plot the points used in the integration. For example:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Sow[{x, Sin[x]}][[2]]
{#[[1]], Plot[f@x, {x, 0, Pi}, Epilog -> Point@#[[2]], 
              Filling -> Axis]} &@Reap@NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, but getting an error. SetDelayed::write: Tag InterpolatingFunction in <<1>>[x_?NumericQ] is Protected. >> and InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {0.0000641782} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."

Comment: @AliGajani Restart your Mathematica session and try again

Comment: Same @belisarius :( Anyway, how come I use NIntegrate on sinx and it won't reveal -cos x but some random pile of numbers. I'd love some guidance in this regard as well. Thank you.

Comment: Belisaius code works fine. Copy/paste it and choose Evaluation->Quit Kernel->Local to remove previous definitions (that are causing the errors). Use Integrate instead of NIntegrate if you want it done symbolically rather than numerically.

Comment: Thanks, that works Bill s. Also, I did  "Integrate Sin x" and it returns 1/2 Integrate Sin x^2 as the output, weird.

Comment: You need to use correct syntax: Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]

Comment: I get that, I am talking about the symbolic integration of sin x which should return -cos x + c , I hope you understand.

Comment: @AliGajani, I think you are looking for the indefinite integral `Integrate[Sin[x], x]`. You may benefit from reading the documentation for `Integrate`, perhaps start here: [How to Do an Integral](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/DoAnIntegral.html)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out just like 15 mins before your reply, Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand the question but you can try this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] Boole[x < y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
    Filling -> 2 -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 500, Epilog -> Inset[NIntegrate[Sin[x], 
      {x, 0, y}], {y, 1/2 Sin[y]}, {Right, Center}]], {y, 0, Pi}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking the question at face value: you can calculate the area of the fill from the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) object that is generated by `Plot`, specifically the [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Polygon.html) expression.

I will use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25172/121) fill method and [my old `polyarea` code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31253/121).

The plot:

```
gr = Plot[{If[x < Pi, Sin[x]], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]
```

[image]

The area:

```
polyarea = 
  Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Transpose@v; 
    Abs[x.RotateLeft@y - RotateLeft@x.y]/2]];

Cases[Normal @ gr, Polygon[a_?ArrayQ] :> polyarea[a], {-4}]
```

> ```
> {1.99894}
> ```

[`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) is needed to convert the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) data into plain coordinate data.

Additional [Plot precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8484/121) will yield additional numeric precision:

```
gr = Plot[{If[x < Pi, Sin[x]], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
      Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
      Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.5}];

Cases[Normal @ gr, Polygon[a_?ArrayQ] :> polyarea[a], {-4}]
```

> ```
> {1.99998}
> ```

For a function that crosses the axis you will need to account for the sign.  For example:

```
Plot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, -7, 20}, Filling -> Axis, Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.2}]

Cases[Normal @ %, Polygon[a_?ArrayQ] :> Sign@Last@Mean@a * polyarea@a, {-4}]

Total @ %
```

[image]

> ```
> {-0.00312878, -1.15988, 7.2798, 3.74814, 11.4189}
>
> 21.2838
> ```

Confirmation of the area calculated with [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html):

```
NIntegrate[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, -7, 20}]
```

> ```
> 21.2838
> ```