# Plot Filling restricted to domain segment

Tags: plotting, customization, filling

I'm trying to plot the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, filling the square area from (0,0) to (1,1) with purple and filling the area under the curve from 1 to 4 with red.

However, *Mathematica* is not showing the purple filling, and the red part is not completely filled down to the x-axis.

My current code:

```
Show[Plot[1/(x^2), {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1],
Plot[{1/(x^2), 1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Purple, None}}}],
Plot[1/(x^2), {x, 1, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Red]]
```

What *Mathematica* gives me:

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

(I'm also very new to *Mathematica*, so any suggestions on a more elegant way to fill the curve would be appreciated.)

Comment: Nearly duplicates: [(9684)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/121), [(18964)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18964/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One `Plot` can do too:

```
Plot[{If[x < 1, 1/(x^2)], If[x > 1, 1/(x^2)]}, {x, 0, 4}
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, Red}}
 , Epilog -> {Purple, Rectangle[]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just the image sampling or is your answer the only one that *doesn't* have the horizontal blue line above the purple shading?

Comment: @bobthechemist Yes there isn't any line. Well, it fits the description, not the image sample but I believe it doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't matter, I just found it curious.

Comment: @bobthechemist There is no line becasue it is only a rectangle and I'm not plottign y=1 at all.

Answer (score 9):

```
Show[Plot[1/(x^2), {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1],
 Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}, FillingStyle -> Purple, Filling -> Bottom, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[1/(x^2), {x, 1, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another variation, using [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
Plot[{
  ConditionalExpression[x^-2, x <= 1],
  ConditionalExpression[x^-2, x > 1],
  ConditionalExpression[1, x <= 1]}
 , {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue,
 Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, Red}, 3 -> {Axis, Purple}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[{x^-2, UnitStep[1 - x], Boole[x > 1] x^-2}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
      Filling -> {3 -> {{2}, {Purple, Red}}}]
```

[image]