# Different curve color and filling in a subdomain of a plot

Tags: plotting

What is an easy way to define a filling and a color for a curve in the subdomain going from $0$ to $1$?

```
Plot[x^-x, {x, 0, 4}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]

I did it with `Show`, but is there exist easy way to use `Filling` or `FillingStyle` to do this in one plot?

```
Show[
  Plot[x^-x, {x, 0, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
  Plot[x^-x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: is this enough: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46339/5478?

Comment: Maybe even better: [Filling between boundaries](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
Plot[{(x^-x) Boole[x <= 1], (x^-x) Boole[x > 1]}, {x, 0, 4},
  Filling -> 1 -> Axis,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
  FillingStyle -> Yellow,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {.001, Automatic}}]
```

[image: plot]