# Fill curve betwen specified abscissa points

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, dynamic, filling

I am plotting the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution of molecular speeds.  I want to be able to select a region to integrate using a manipulate function.  Then I want to have that same region filled in on the plot.  How can this be done?  I can't seem to get filling to work quite correctly.

```
f[u_] := 
  4 Pi ( (m)/(2 Pi kb T))^(3/2) u^2 Exp[ -(m u^2)/(2 kb T)];
subs = { kb -> 1.3806 * 10^(-23), T -> 300, m -> .0032/(6*10^(23))};
Plot[f[u] /. subs , {u, 0, 5000}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Filling -> {1000 -> Axis}]
Integrate[f[u] /. subs, {u, 1000, 2000}]

Manipulate[ 
 Integrate[f[u] /. subs, 
 {u, a, b}], 
 {a, 0, 5000}, 
 {b, 0, 5000} ]
```

Comment: This [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18964/3066) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also try `UnitStep`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[u] /. subs, 
   f[u] UnitStep[u - a] UnitStep[b - u] /. subs}, {u, 0, 5000}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{{a, f[a] /. subs}, {b, f[b] /. subs}}]}] , {a, 0, 
  4000}, {b, 100, 4000}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you want to do something like

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Row[{With[{a = a, b = b}, HoldForm[Integrate[f[u] /. subs, {u, a, b}]]], 
             Integrate[f[u] /. subs, {u, a, b}]}, "  =  "], 
             Plot[{ConditionalExpression[f[u] /. subs, a <= u <= b], f[u] /. subs}, 
             {u, 0, 5000}, PlotRange -> All, 
             Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, ImageSize -> 400]}],
 {a, 0, 5000}, {b, 0, 5000}]
```

Note: You can also use

```
Piecewise[{{f[u], a <= u <= b}}, Indeterminate] /. subs
```

or

```
Boole[a <= u <= b] f[u]/.subs
```

instead of `ConditionalExpression[f[u] /. subs, a <= u <= b]`.

[image]

See also: [this answer to a related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9688/125)

Comment: kguler I think that this question is a duplicate of the one you link with **See also:** -- do you disagree, and if so, why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it looks so..