# Can you Plot over some range but apply the "Filling" option over a smaller range?

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to shade the area between a function, and a line, but only over a specific range. This range is smaller than the range of the entire plot. The example code and plot below make my goal more clear.

```
R4 = 8.3144621;(*m^3 Pa K^-1mol^-1 *)
pvDw[T_, V_, Rr_, a_, b_] = 
p /. Solve[(p + a/V^2) (V - b) == Rr T, p] // First

aAr = 0.1355; (*a*)
bAr = .000032;(*b*)
TAr = 130;
guesspv = 2.6*10^6;
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, 
    bAr], {Vm, (3.2*10^-5), (1.0*10^-3)}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {guesspv, Yellow}}]]
```

This code generates this figure

[image: plot]

I would like to be able to show the shading only in the 2nd and third regions not the first and fouth.  How would I go about doing this?

I realize that using the Filling option may not be the best way to do this also, so I am open to hearing about other options, plot types ect. I used Filling in the title because that is what I am using in my flawed solution.

Comment: Related: [(9684)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/121),
[(14696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14696/121),
[(18964)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18964/121),
[(25169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25169/121),
[(46332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46332/121),
[(61743)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61743/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(Last @@@ NSolve[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr] == guesspv, {Vm}]); 

Plot[{ConditionalExpression[guesspv, min < Vm < max], 
      Evaluate[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr]]}, {Vm, (3.2*10^-5), (1.0*10^-3)},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Thin, Yellow}], Directive[{Thick, Black}]},
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}}]
```

[image]

Explanatory notes:

Find the intersection of the curve with `guesspv`:

```
soln = NSolve[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr] == guesspv, {Vm}] ;
(* {{Vm -> 0.000285782},{Vm -> 0.000107816},{Vm -> 0. 0000541249}} *)
```

See [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html):

```
intersections = Last @@@ soln   (* same as  Vm /. soln  to get the RHSs of ->s*)
(* {0.000285782,0.000107816,0.0000541249}
```

See [Prefix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html), [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html):

```
Min@intersections (* same as Min[intersections]*)
(* 0.0000541249 *)
Max@intersections (* same as Max[intersections]*)
(* 0.000285782 *)
```

Define a function to do the previous two steps in a single step:

```
function = {Min@#, Max@#} &  ;(* same as {Min[#], Max[#]}& *)
function@intersections (* same as function[intersections] *)
(* {0.0000541249,0.000285782} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, Could you explain the syntax you use on the first line of your answer, or provide a reference where I could figure it out?

Comment: I use [ConditionalExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) to define function that takes the value `guesspv` if `Vm` falls in regions 2 and 3 (that is, if `min < Vm < max`, where `min` and `max` are the smallest and largest `Vm` values where your curve intersects the line at `guesspv` - these are obtained using `Solve`), the value `Indeterminate` otherwise. We plot the two functions in a single plot.

Comment: ... `Filling->{1->{{2},Yellow}` says use `Yellow` filling between the first and second functions in the list of functions in `Plot`s first argument (see [Filling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html) for more examples.

Comment: I am sorry I meant specifically the line where you define Min and max, for example what does @# mean in the line `{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(Last @@@ NSolve[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr] == guesspv, {Vm}]);` ?

Comment: Oh I see.. give me a few minutes to add some references.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to show two plots one with filling and one without.

```
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(Last @@@ 
     NSolve[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr] == guesspv, {Vm}]);
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, 
    bAr]], {Vm, (3.2*10^-5), (1.0*10^-3)}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PlotRange -> Automatic], 
 Plot[Evaluate[pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr]], {Vm, min, max}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {guesspv, Yellow}}]]
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
   pvDw[TAr, Vm, R4, aAr, bAr], {Vm, (3.2*10^-5), (1.0*10^-3)}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {guesspv, Yellow}}] /. 
 GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[__], Polygon[y__]}] :> 
  GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[y]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this rather easily using `Show`. Here is a simple example.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
plot1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}];
plot2 = Plot[f[x], {x, 1/3, 2/3}, Filling -> 1/3];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]