# How can I plot a curve with a filled sub-domain?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a curve with a filled sub-domain as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Make two `Plot`s with a different V range, use `Filling` in one, combine them with `Show`.  What have you tried so far? Did you look at the `Plot` documentation?

Comment: closely related Q/A: [Filling between boundaries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `f` be the function to plot. Define a 2nd function, `g` that restricts `f` to the given sub-domain. Use the fill option `Filling -> 2 -> Axis`.

```
f[x_] := 1/x^2
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{f[x], 3/2 <= x <= 2}}, Null]

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 1, 4},
  Filling -> 2 -> Axis,
  PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: @user45951. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.