# Filling and colouring

Tags: plotting, color, filling

I am plotting to functions that look like this:

[image: Example]

I have used `Filling -> Axis` inside a plot and it produces the above example. My question is if I can more control over the coloring.

Specifically, I would like to set **the area below the two curves** to a color while setting all the other ares to white (no coloring).  Notice that this is different from coloring the intersection or the area between the two curves. Any suggestions?

Comment: It always (?) helps us to help you if you post your unsatisfactory code so we can cut'n'paste it and tweak it.  I'm far too lazy to experiment to answer your question *ab initio*.  I suspect other people around here are too busy but either way, show us yer code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(9684)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9684/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
Plot[{
  ConditionalExpression[x^2, x < 1],
  ConditionalExpression[x^2, x > 1],
  ConditionalExpression[2 + 2 x^2, x < 1]
  },
 {x, 0, 2},
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
threshold = 1.;

Plot[{x^2, x^2/6, ConditionalExpression[0, x <= threshold]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Orange, None}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, {None, LightOrange}}},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

and

```
Plot[{x^2, x^2/6, Boole[x > threshold ]}, {x, 0, 2},
 Exclusions -> {{threshold }},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Orange, None}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, {None,LightOrange}}},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]