# Filling complex areas of a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a ListPlot with vertical and horizontal lines. I would like to color the resulting rectangles by something like "Fill with Green if less than both line 1 & line 3". However, I can't figure out how to make this logic work with Filling.

Two examples of non-working code below:
The first displays a strange band of green underneath line 1.

```
 ListPlot[{
  (*Horizontal line 1*){{0, 5}, {35, 5}},
  (*Horizontal line 2*){{0, 10}, {35, 10}},
  (*Vertical line 3*){{5, 0}, {5, 35}},
  (*Vertical line 4*){{10, 0}, {10, 35}}},
 Joined -> True,
 Filling -> {1 -> 3}, FillingStyle -> LightGreen]
```

[image]

The second displays no filling at all.

```
 ListPlot[{
  (*Horizontal line 1*){{0, 5}, {35, 5}},
  (*Horizontal line 2*){{0, 10}, {35, 10}},
  (*Vertical line 3*){{5, 0}, {5, 35}},
  (*Vertical line 4*){{10, 0}, {10, 35}}},
 Joined -> True,
 Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, FillingStyle -> LightGreen]
```

[image]

Eventually the locations of the lines will be controlled via Manipulate. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very closely related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223568/731) question. Here is a version of kglr's answer adapted to your problem:

```
ListPlot[{
  (*Horizontal line 1*){{0, 5}, {35, 5}},
  (*Horizontal line 2*){{0, 10}, {35, 10}},
  (*Vertical line 3*){{5, 0}, {5, 35}},
  (*Vertical line 4*){{10, 0}, {10, 35}},
  (*Horizontal line 5*){{0, 0}, {5, 0}}
  },
 Joined -> True,
 Filling -> {1 -> {5}},
 FillingStyle -> LightGreen,
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, None}
 ]
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, the key is to create a shorter line that goes between $x=0$ and $x=5$ where 5 is the position of the vertical line. Then you can fill between the chosen full length horizontal line and this shorter other horizontal line to get what you want, since you cannot use vertical lines with the `Filling` option.

For full flexibility, I would consider using `Graphics` instead:

```
Graphics[{
  LightGreen, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}],
  Gray,
  InfiniteLine[{0, 5}, {1, 0}],
  InfiniteLine[{0, 10}, {1, 0}],
  InfiniteLine[{5, 0}, {0, 1}],
  InfiniteLine[{10, 0}, {0, 1}]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}
 ]
```

[image: Output]

`AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`, which may or may not be wanted, is used here to match the output of `ListPlot`.

You might also consider adding the `Rectangle` to the `ListPlot` using the `Prolog` or `Epilog` option (probably `Prolog` so that the rectangle goes under the lines).