# How to draw two vertical lines into a Plot or ParametricPlot and fill / shade the region between them?

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

I will give an example of a regular `Plot`, but I also need this to work for a `ParametricPlot`. Say I have

```
plt1=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2π}]
```

I now want to add two vertical lines, one at `x=3π/4` abd on at `x=5π/4`. In addition, I want to shade the region between those two lines. My initial idea was to use `ParametricPlot` to draw the line, and I hoped it would have a `Filling`option similar to that of `Plot`, but it does not.

The next idea was to use

```
plt2=RegionPlot[3π/4<x<5π/4,{x,0,2π},{y,-1.5,1.5}]
```

where I deliberately draw the box a bit larger on the y-coordinate, since I want it to be clipped at the `PlotRange` of `plt1`. Now I thought I combine both plots by

```
Show[plt1,plt2]
```

which gives

[image]

And this es exactly as I want it, with the one exception that

1. the shaded region contains that weird mesh of thin lines.

This problem disappears if I show them in opposite order

```
Show[plt2, plt1]
```

which gives

[image]

But it also introduces the new problems that

2. the plot range would have to be manually adjusted
3. the plot is now shown with these boxed axes style, and I am not sure
   how to change it to the usual one of `Plot`.

Problem 2. is admittedly the lesser problem. But if someone could help me fix preferably 1. or otherwise 3. that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filling complex areas of a ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223875/filling-complex-areas-of-a-listplot)

Comment: @C.E. I Suppose it would work, thanks! The answer of Suba Thomas below might be even simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) is useful here.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 Prolog -> {LightBlue, Rectangle[{3 π/4, -2}, {5 π/4, 2}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and simple solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to pimp the box in your answer a bit, use: `Prolog -> {Opacity[.2], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
  EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]]], 
  Rectangle[{3 π/4, -2}, {5 π/4, 2}]}`. ; )  That is the same blue tone as the plot line, and it has the vertical lines left and right. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, 'pimp' it to your heart's content. :) And, in case you didn't know, the default plot style is easier remembered as `ColorData[97, 1]`.

Comment: Didn't know! Thanks once more. (I knew ColorData[97,"ColorList"] and then copy-pasted the desired color so far.)